# C++ Program will not exit while loop

Tags: c++

My C++ program will not exit while loop below when the user enters either 'Q' or 'q' to quit the program. The first two options work fine and call their appropriate functions, but the 'Quit the program' option just starts the while loop over again indefinitely.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char choice; //Varible to hold the user's choice.

    while (choice != 'Q' || choice != 'q')
    {
        //Display the menu and retrieve the user's choice.
        cout << "Please choose from one of the options below:\n\n";
        cout << "A. Calculate the total amount of your bill [Enter A]\n";
        cout << "B. Calculate your BMI [ENTER B]\n";
        cout << "Q. Quit the program [Enter Q]\n\n";
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        //Either calculate the user's bill or their BMI based on their choice.
        if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a')
        {
            caLculateBillAmount();
        }
        else if (choice == 'B' || choice == 'b')
        {
            calculateBMI();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need an logical and (Also you should check cin)

Comment: You should use `do { ... } while (choice != 'Q' || choice != 'q')` here as in your case choice is initially undefined.

Comment: 101: if you don't see the problem, substitute the letter to that expression and evaluate it in your head...

Comment: Or initialise `choice` to something other than `'Q'` or `'q'` (that's my suggestion)

Comment: As well as the rest, you probably need to eat up newlines. Common error.

Comment: Look into the functions `tolower` and `toupper` so you don't have to worry about case-sensitive comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply use `while (choice !='Q' && choice !='q') {...}`. And yes, you should initialize `choice` to something different from 'Q' and 'q'. Just do something like `char choice=0;`.

Comment: And also initialize `choice` to be something different than `Q` or `q`.

Comment: Use something like `while (toupper(choice) != 'Q')` and not worry about comparing against the lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself what the following evaluates to:

```
choice != 'Q' || choice != 'q'
```

If choice is 'Q' then choice is not 'q' so the right-half of the test is true.

If choice is 'q' then choice is not 'Q' so the left-half of the test is true.

You need to use && in place of ||, or you could simply use toupper(choice) != 'Q'.